# mutt regex for limit filters

Tags: email, regex, mutt

Does mutt support multi-line regex for its search filters? I cannot find an yes or no in the [documentation](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-4.html#regexp). I'm assuming its not supported, but cannot tell if maybe I am improperly escaping my regex.

I'm trying to match email body that contains something along these lines:

```
...
...(22)

sent ...
....
```

My regex I'm using for the limit command is:

```
~b \\(22\\)\n\nsent
```

I assume no multiline because this works as expected:

```
~b \\(22\\)\n
```

Comment: Huh, looks like it does not. At the risk of false positives you could do perhaps `~b \\(22\\)$ ~b ^sent` to get messages with lines ending and beginning with the desired bits.

Comment: This is the problem. I want specifically 1 blank line between the line ending in "(22)" and the line starting with "sent". There are some messages with text rather than a blank line, which is what I'm trying to filter.